# How do I update a temporary field from a subquery on the same mysql table (avoiding MySql error #1093 )

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table of students scores called marksheet.

```
id  |   student |   score   |   position  
1   |   Adora   |   50      |   
2   |   Sam     |   76      |   
3   |   Frank   |   40      |   


SELECT id, 1+(SELECT count(*) from marksheet a WHERE a.score >   
b.score) as student_rank 
FROM marksheet b


id  |   student |   score   |   student_rank  
1   |   Adora   |   50      |   2   
2   |   Sam     |   76      |   1  
3   |   Frank   |   40      |   3
```

The problem is, I want to run the ranking query and the update query at the same time. I want the ranks to be stored in the table as position.
So I run:

```
UPDATE marksheet AS marks SET  marks.position =
(SELECT id, 1+(SELECT count(*) from marksheet a WHERE a.score >   
b.score) as student_rank 
FROM marksheet b ) ;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1093 - Table 'marksheet' is specified twice, both as a target for  
'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

I have browsed through stackoverflow for similar cases of updating a table by a subquery of itself. I came across lots of examples which I learned a thing or two, however, I tried adapting the examples without success. Any suggestions is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use an alias for the marksheet table and then JOIN it with the original table, like this:

```
UPDATE marksheet AS marks
JOIN ( 
  SELECT id, 1+(SELECT count(*) from marksheet a WHERE a.score >   
  b.score) as student_rank 
  FROM marksheet b
) t
SET  marks.position = t.student_rank
WHERE marks.id = t.id
```

Comment: that is highly appreciated. I couldn't have figured it out. I guess I need to read about JOIN a lot more. Thank you very much. It works like magic. I was already thinking of using php compromising efficiency. I am so glad. This is awesome.

Comment: @SamRans you are welcome, I am glad it worked for you. UPDATE cannot be used on same table from where you are doing a SELECT. Which is why you have to make an alias and then join.